# Circuit problem with different resistors and analysis of voltage of electrons

Tags: electricity

So when I was learning electricity I had this confusion: assume there are 2 circuits, first is connected a resistor with very high resistance, second is connected to a resistor with very low resistance.

Now a battery with a field that generates some voltage of N in electrons is set up, and assume that wires have negligible resistance. The potential difference across both resistors would be N. Why does the electron carrying the energy use up the same (15J) value of energy when passing through the 2 different resistors? What is the energy used for and processed to on the microscopic level of the electron?

Comment: I don't know how to answer at the solid-state physics level, but I can tell you that the reason the low-resistance circuit dissipates more power is because, even though each electron has the same energy in either case, a lot more of them flow through the lower-valued resistor than flow through the high valued resistor during any given interval of time.

Comment: One possible confusion:  voltage isn't measured in number of  electrons.